# Querying for words ending with, with the ReversedWildcardFilterFactory and KeywordTokenizerFactory

Tags: solr, wildcard

I have the "text_general_rev" filed type declared in my Solr schema(.xml) like so:

```
<fieldType
    name="text_general_rev"
    class="solr.TextField"
    positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
       <filter
            class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"
            withOriginal="true"
            maxPosAsterisk="2"
            maxPosQuestion="2"
            maxFractionAsterisk="1.0" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />                
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have 2 Solr documents with the "artist" field set as "text_general_rev" like so:

*Document1 artist is "Jimmy Jones Tim Coco Mimi"*

*Document2 artist is "Jones Jimmy Tim Bobo Mimi"*

If I do searches of the kind "start with something" they work as I want to:

`+artist:(J*)` returns Document 1 and 2

`+artist:(Jim*)` returns Document 1

`+artist:(Jimmy Jo*)` returns Document 1

On the other hand, similar queries, but of type "ends with something don't work similarly:

`+artist:(*Mimi)` returns Document 1 and 2  (which is ok)

`+artist:(*Coco Mimi)` return 0 results (which is not ok)

`+artist:("*Coco Mimi")` return 0 results (which is not ok)

`+artist:(*co Mimi)` return 0 results (which is not ok)

`+artist:("*co Mimi")` return 0 results (which is not ok)

My question is why is this happening? Is it normal, and if so what am I missing? I've tried multiple values for maxFractionAsterisk (like 0, 0.5, 1, etc. This is the only config param of the ReversedWildcardFilterFactory which I don't fully understand).

Comment: what is your field type of artist ? as you mentioned the field type is for title ?

Comment: @Jayendra a doh I misscopied the code. It's the same field, I'll correct it now.

Comment: How are you firing your query ? What request handler are you using ? Cause if i use the default handler it matches the results. Remember wildcard queries do not undergo any analysis so the lower case filter is not applicable for query terms with a * . So *Co or Coco* will not match any documents as the lower case filter is applied only at index time. J* will also not match any results.